# Запуск внутренней функции

Tags: javascript

Почему, не выводится alert если мы запускаем функцию extFunc()?

```
 function extFunc() {
     var a = 123;
     return function intFunc() {
     alert(a);
   }
 }
extFunc() // ----
```

Но alert выводится, если присвоить функцию переменной и запустить через эту переменную? Какие возможности открывает здесь присвоение функции переменной? Спасибо!

```
var newFunc = extFunc();
newFunc(); // 123
```

Comment: Никаких новых возможностей... Попробуйте `extFunc()();` Переменная сама по себе тут не при делах.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В первоначальном варианте extFunc возвращает функцию, но не вызывает ее. Во втором варианте вы помещаете функцию, которую вернула extFunc в переменную newFunc и затем вызываете ее. Первый вариант будет работать в таком виде

```js
function extFunc() {
     var a = 123;
     return function intFunc() {
     alert(a);
   }
 }
extFunc()()
```

Comment: Т.е. если мы присваиваем переменной функцию, то вызов через эту переменную будет автоматически запускать все вложенные функции?

Comment: Нет. Смотрите. extFunc **возвращает** функцию и вы помещаете эту возвращенную функцию в newFunc. И когда вы используете конструкцию **newFunc()** вызывается не вложенная функция, а функция, которая находится в переменной newFunc

Comment: Мне не понятно почему тогда newFunc() вызывает вложенную функцию без доп. вызова newFunc()(); Т.е. newFunc() получает сразу управление над всеми вложенными в нее функциями и сразу их запускает?

Comment: Она не вызывает вложенную функцию. newFunc() - это вызов функции, которая лежит в переменной newFunc. А лежит там то, что вернула extFunc после вызова extFunc().  **newFunc()()** можно рассматривать, читая слева направо: сначала вызывается newFunc, которая возвращает функцию, и затем эта функция вызывается следующими ()

Comment: Понятно, но не до конца) Спасибо! Подскажите, пожалуйста, какую тему нужно ее почитать, чтобы окончательно вошло? Замыкания?

Comment: Да. [Возврат функции](https://learn.javascript.ru/closures)

Comment: Спасибо большое!